# Any reason why Angularjs behaviour is different in an iframe?

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJs app which runs in two parts. The "master" portion runs in a parent window, and the "child" portion(s) run in iframe(s) within that window. The app is structured such that the iframe(s) can be popped out and run in their own windows (which is why they are implemented as iframes).

The issue I have is that the app behaves differently when "docked" v. in its own window.

Specifically I have

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">status = {{wrapper.status}}</div>
```

Which when popped out correctly displays "status=1", but when docked displays "status = {{wrapper.status}}"

Comment: when you say its docked, is it in iframes at that time also?

Comment: yes. to explain differently, I have parent.html and child.html. At any time, parent.html can have a number of iframes, each containing a copy of child.html. Additionally, the use can view child.html in its own window, ie. not as an iframe.

Comment: I have Angular running in an iframe, but not as a sub-unit of another app. It's its own app. What exactly is different about the behavior?

Comment: May be when you pop out any of your child window, you do not maintain a child parent reference between the two.

Comment: @Sharondio the different behaviour is in the last line of my original question. ""Which when popped out correctly displays "status=1", but when docked displays "status = {{wrapper.status}}""

Comment: @codef0rmer there is no relationship between the child and parent. Because child can run as an orphan, it is completely self-contained. Just to clarify, the popped-out/orphaned behvaiour is the correct one. It's when the child is running as an iframe within parent that I get the incorrect behaviour.

Comment: sharing a small demo would be helpful to understand the problem more clearly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [inserting iframe from trusted source in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051061/inserting-iframe-from-trusted-source-in-angularjs)