# inserting iframe from trusted source in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, ng-bind-html, angularjs-sce

Trying to use `ng-bind-html` to insert iframe into page with AngularJS & I can't get it to work it on even the simplest form.

**Javascript**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
   $scope.showIt = '<iframe src="http://www.anything.com"></iframe>';
}
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div ng-bind-html="showIt"></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service to tell angular to render html content on view

**Angular Doc says**

> $sce is a service that provides **Strict Contextual Escaping** services to
>   AngularJS.
>   SCE assists in writing code in way that (a) is secure by default and
>   (b) makes auditing for security vulnerabilities such as XSS,
>   clickjacking, etc. a lot easier.

Before doing it, you need to inject `ngSanitize` dependency inside your app

You can do it in two way either using `filter` or `controller`

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    Using Filter
    <div ng-bind-html="showIt | toTrusted"></div>
    Using Controller
    <div ng-bind-html="htmlSafe(showIt)"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']).
controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.showIt = '<iframe src="http://www.anything.com"></iframe>';
    $scope.htmlSafe = function (data) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
    }
}).
filter('toTrusted', function ($sce) {
    return function (value) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(value);
    };
});
```

From angular 1.2 onwards $sce feature is enabled for below version you should enable/disable it in config phase of angular.

```
app.config(['$sceProvider', function($sceProvider) {
    $sceProvider.enabled(true);
}]);
```

Here is [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95yomb4y/2/)

Comment: What if I don't want it sanitized?

Comment: @Amidude  which version of angular you are using?

Comment: @Amidude you've to include `ngSanitize` module inside your app. take a look at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml example

Comment: using the latest version. 1.3. Thank you for all of your help. I'm working through the issues and I thank you for the Fiddle and examples/link.