# URL Preview with tagline and logo in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web-frontend

I have an assignment to implement a preview of an URL which means it will display the logo and tagline just like facebook.

I know that we have urLive library in jQuery but i have to implement in angularjs.I have tried following code but it doesn't work.

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
        <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <iframe ng-src="{{currentUrl}}"> </iframe>
        </div>

        <script>
            var app=angular.module('myapp',[]);
                app.controller('AppCtrl',function($scope,$sce){
                $scope.currentUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://facebook.com");
            }); 
       </script>
```

Do we have any such thing in angularjs?`

Answer (score 0):

You missing couple of things

1. Add missing Angular sanitize reference
2. Inject `'ngSanitize'` module inside you add

**CODE**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>


   <script>
        angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize'])
            app.controller('AppCtrl',function($scope,$sce){
            $scope.currentUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://facebook.com");
        }); 
   </script>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3J25M/83/)

You can also do it by making it angular filter like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051061/inserting-iframe-from-trusted-source-in-angularjs/28051175#28051175)

> **NOTE**
>
> You can not load http://www.facebook.com inside iframe refer [this SO
> Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680215/load-facebook-into-an-iframe) for more information.

Hope this could help you. Thanks

Comment: can you give the code how you added angular references? Thats last thing i can take a look

Comment: <html ng-app="myapp"><body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <iframe ng-src="{{currentUrl}}"> </iframe>
        <script>
        var app=angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);
        app.controller('AppCtrl',function($scope,$sce){
        $scope.currentUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://anything.com");
 });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script></body></html>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70257/discussion-on-answer-by-pankajparkar-url-preview-with-tagline-and-logo-in-angula).

Comment: @pankajparkar Since I moved the comments to chat, they should be able to join.