# How use ng-bind-html-unsafe in AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs

I use an editor to add comment and this content save as html in db. When I want to display it in page all html elements appear in out put. So I want to use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/HQpQH/) code to solve my problem but not solve it.

Here is my code

Data include {body, name, date} that body save as html

```
  <div ng-repeat="d in Data">
       <div class='content'>
           <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="d.body">
                 <p>{{d.body}}</p>
           </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: which angular version you are using? you may need to include angular-sanitize

Comment: ng-bind-html-unsafe has been depecrated in latest version, you need to use $sce service then make html as `$sce.trustAsHtml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jsfiddle inside an question is using angular 1.1 in which ng-bind-html-unsafe is working.

But currently angular has deprecated `ng-bind-html-unsafe` from latest version, instead you need to use `ng-bind-html` then sanitize that url from the angular filter using `$sce` service and `$sce.trustedAsHtml()`

**Filter**

```
app.filter("sanitize", ['$sce', function($sce) {
        return function(htmlCode){
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
        }
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-repeat="d in Data">
       <div class='content'>
           <div ng-bind-html="d.body | sanitize">
                 <p>{{d.body}}</p>
           </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

For more info refer this [**SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051061/inserting-iframe-from-trusted-source-in-angularjs)