# How to change text in div by angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

**js code:**

```
myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#divData'));
myEl.text('This is text.');
```

this way I can change the text of `#divData` element. But I want to add some html code like, `<b>This is a bold text</b>`. But It's getting rendered as it is. But I want output as **This is a bold text**. Please provide me a solution through only angularJS.

Comment: You could check this [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28051175/2435473), seems similar to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
myEl.html('This is text.');
```

instead of `text`

Answer (score 4):

Please check the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 3):

Just add html tags to text apparently not works well. I believe thats its to only add 'text' not elements. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Follows plunker. With two cases. One of official documentation and other with answers posted here.

```
(function(angular) {
 'use strict';
  angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.myHTML =
   'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
   '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';

$scope.executar = function(){
  var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#divData'));
  myEl.text('<b>This is a bold text</b>');
};
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/1Hnb018XstMYfynr34nJ?p=preview

Advice of Sebastian Sebald its good. Go ahead documentation. 
I also did not know until five minutes ago. I just learn now.

Answer (score 0):

use .html if you want to assign html.

```
myEl.html('<b>This is a bold text</b>');
```